# Extending Range + Same network on both routers

Tags: router, ip, home-networking, subnet

I have 2 routers. I need 2 because my house is large.
But I also want to be to access the upstairs network and ssh if needed into the family computer or connect to the printer etc. This is not possible.
My main network is 192.168.0.1. I connected second router with Ethernet cable from the downstairs one. The router upstairs has 192.168.1.1 network/subnet whatever.

I cannot see or interact with devices on that network.
YET I can access the first router's(downstairs router) setting page from the second one(upstairs router).

I wanted to get some CCNA knowledge so I researched some courses. But after hours of material, I knew nothing about how to configure 2 routers so that they share the same network.

How do I configure them? Nothing happens when I turn off DHCP on the second router. I managed to do it sometimes where I could access the computers only on WiFi, not LAN or *vice versa*.

I want all to share the same 192.168.0.1 connection regardless if they are connected to WiFi or LAN.

Comment: What are the routers, and do they have AP mode?

Answer (score 0):

That you have connected router 2 to the network by Ethernet is excellent.

Connect the second router to the network on a LAN port of router 2 (not WAN).

Give it a Static IP on the network so it always has the same address. Assuming your main network is 100 - 200 for DCHP, give router 2 address .10 well away from the DHCP range (for your own clarity).

Turn DHCP OFF on router 2 (only have 1 DHCP server). This will make the Router work essentially as an Access Point.

Make sure all devices have Network Discovery ON (and probably File/Print sharing)

Restart router 2 ( and router 1 first for good measure). Also restart Devices if you changed Network Discovery.

Now, assuming the settings are correct, everything will be on one subnet and all devices will be visible on the network including a printer.

I have a main floor network and an upstairs network (Ethernet up inside a closet) and second floor network. All on one subnet, all works, printer works for all devices.

================

This exercise will be helpful for the knowledge you are trying to learn and get.

One subnet is nice and simple (I do this too) and makes adding / seeing devices easy.

Answer (score 0):

What John has said is essentially correct.  My answer is largely the same but maybe easier to understand and uses more correct terms.

YOU DON'T WANT 2 devices acting as routers on your home network.  What you want is to keep the main router acting as the router/gateway and change the second router into an AP.

Routers forward packets based on IP information, while APs act like wireless switches.   Your routers are, in essence  a router + AP + switch.  The solution is to disable the router functionality on one of the routers.  Here is how -

1. Assign the router you are turning into sn AP (I'll call it AP) a static IP address in the same subnet as the router LAN.  Put it outside the dhcp range.  192.168.1.2 or 192.168.1.254 are common choices.
2. Disable DHCP on the AP.  DHCP gives out IP addresses to other devices.  The AP does not have a gateway and will conflict with the DHCP server on the router.
3. Tape over the WAN port on the AP.  You dont want to plug anything into it.
4. Set up the WIFI on thecAP. You want to set it up with the same SSID and password as on the router.  If not set to auto for the channel, ensure the channel is at least 3 channels above or below the channel on the router.  Same applies on the 5 gig spectrum if it applies.  Gaving the same SSID and password means you can connect to either wifi connection without changing your computers IP or wifi settings.
5. Connect a LAN port on the AP to a LAN port on the router.

Comment: Thanks.  A router with DHCP OFF works essentially as an AP.  I have use second routers for years.  I added that clarification to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most 'modern' routers have 'AP mode' - specifically designed for this situation. You want that (and that should convert your 'wan' port into a regular lan port. There may also be a option that isolates wifi clients - you'd want it off. While historically there were specific options for roaming you 'just' need to set the same SSID and password on both channels on each router and each router, and the clients 'just' roam automatically.

While I'd *done* what the answers suggested before, 'turn off DHCP specifically, and plug in the wan port' isn't really needed a lot of the time.